# SCVMM 2016 console not loading after UR3 (?)

Tags: scvmm

I'm managing several servers with SCVMM, and just the other day the VMM console lost connection to the server, and is now refusing to connect. I think it coincided with the CU3 update that came over Windows Update, but that might be a red herring.

When I try to open the console, the splash screen shows for several seconds, then it switches to a "Attempting to reconnect" window, saying "The connection to Virtual Machine Manager Server […] was lost.", which closes almost immediately, replaced by the splash screen again.

I ran the debug logs on both the host and the client site, and on the host side I've dug out the following exceptions:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80338102): The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The WMI service reported that the WMI provider could not perform the requested operation.

Later in the log:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader+ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.

And later:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'

On the console side:

> Microsoft.VirtualManager.Utils.CarmineException: The connection to the VMM management server sc-vmm was lost.  Ensure that sc-vmm is online and that you can access the server remotely from your computer. Then connect to sc-vmm and try the command again using the new connection. Or, you can ensure that the Virtual Machine Manager service is started on sc-vmm. Then connect to sc-vmm and try the command again using the new connection. If the command fails again because of a connection failure, restart the Virtual Manager service and then try the operation again.

By the way, I can run commands against the server in powershell from the server, so it seems to be running.. It seems to be just the consoles acting up.

And yes, I have installed UR3 for the console.

Any idea what may have caused it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

So after a bunch of time trying different things, I stumbled on a blog post, saying to close all VMM Consoles before running the installed.. Seems like I forgot to close one on a remote server, and that messed up the installer.

So what I had to do is download the UR3 installer again (there are download links [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4014528/update-rollup-3-for-system-center-2016-virtual-machine-manager)) and install it AGAIN on the same server, using msiexec.

After doing that on both clustered servers, and restarting them just in case, the consoles now open!